# What does size mean in gwt panel?

Tags: html, gwt

I saw some tags like:

```
<g:west size='192'>
```

What does the "size" mean here? Width, Height or percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has an [example](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html).

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
    <g:north size='5'>
```

This size is means 5em (from top)

Your size means 192 Units width from the left. (Default is PX)

Comment: it makes sense. BTW, I think <g:west size='192'> means 192 Units from the left, right?

Comment: Ohh .. west is at the left side, 192px width.